# Google OAuth integration with fastapi

Tags: python, angular, oauth, fastapi, fastapiusers

We use fastapi-users to integrate [Google auth](https://fastapi-users.github.io/fastapi-users/10.4/). By default there are defined to endpoints `/auth/google/authorize` and `/auth/google/callback`.

So frontend which is in Angular calls `/auth/google/authorize` and as result we got URL in body. Than if we call this URL we got CORS error. After that we are not sure if this is right approach or on which order should we call API.

Also API `/auth/google/callback` has code, code_verifier, state and error fields where we get this fields?

[image]

We use fastapi-users package in our backend. We have major problems with integrating Google OAuth.
URL: [google auth](https://fastapi-users.github.io/fastapi-users/10.4/)
By default there are two endpoints `/auth/google/authorize` and `/auth/google/callback`.

What is actually a flow for these endpoints? When we call the /auth/google/authorize endpoint, the response is:

[image]

We tried then calling this URL again in the frontend, because if we copy paste this URL in google, the response is token and token type.
If we call this endpoint in our frontend, we get CORS error.

Is this even right approach? What frontend should do with these two endpoints? And what to do with the /auth/google/callback endpoint?

Thanks to everyone for help

Answer (score 0):

The CORS error you are receiving is likely because you forgot to put allowed origins in your `config` or `app.py` file of your FastAPI application. Once you receive the token from your `/auth/google/callback` endpoint. You'll need to use this token in subsequent requests to let the server know and verify that the current user making the request is actually who the user claims to be and what roles the user claims to possess.

So, the actual flow is something like this:

1. First the `/auth/google/authorize` endpoint gets called which responds back with a redirection url. In the frontend, you'll need to redirect to this url which opens a google dialog box with your google accounts.
2. Once you authorize any google account to be associated with your application, it redirects you to the redirect url you set up during the google oauth credentials creation. In your case its likely `/auth/google/callback`
3. This endpoint then sends back an access_token which needs to be stored in  your frontend client to make subsequent api calls for your protected resources.